# Dilate image to remove gaps and get dilated contours in the original contours size

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mathematical-morphology

I'm trying to remove the gaps or holes in any given shape in an image.

The alternative I'm following to accomplish this is: I'm thresholding the image to get a binary image and apply dilation to eliminate the gaps, but this results in a grown bigger shape. How can I scale in these dilated contours to be the same size as the original image's contours? or can I dilate the image and still have the same size as the original shape somehow? Is there any better alternative?

I have tried applying dilation and then scaling in the contours of the dilated image, but haven't been able to do it in a way that always results in the dilated contour having the same size as the original contours (sometimes the dilated and scaled contours have the same size as the original contours, sometimes not).

Also, how could I make sure to apply dilation in a way that always removes the gaps of the original image, no matter how big or small its shapes are? I realized that sometimes dilation happens in a way that gaps are still visible but minimized instead of removed, which is not the goal.

This is what I have until now:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageCms
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 99999999999999

import numpy as np

import cv2
import numpy
img_path = 'input.png'

def cmyk_to_rgb(cmyk_img):
    img = Image.open(cmyk_img)
    if img.mode == "CMYK":
        img = ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, "Color Profiles\\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc", "Color Profiles\\sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm", outputMode="RGB")
    return cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

def cv_threshold(img, thresh=254, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV):
    if len(img.shape) == 3:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    threshed = cv2.threshold(img, thresh, maxval, type)[1]
    return threshed

def find_contours(img, to_gray=None):
    kernel   = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
    morphed  = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    contours = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    return contours[-2]

def mask_from_contours(ref_img, contours):
    mask = numpy.zeros(ref_img.shape, numpy.uint8)
    mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 24)
    return cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def dilate_mask(mask, kernel_size=10):
    kernel  = numpy.ones((kernel_size,kernel_size), numpy.uint8)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
    return dilated

def draw_contours(src_img, contours):
    canvas = cv2.drawContours(src_img.copy(), contours, 0, (0,255,0), 24)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[-1])
    cv2.rectangle(canvas, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
    return canvas

def scale_contour(cnt, scale):
    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

    cnt_norm = cnt - [cx, cy]
    cnt_scaled = cnt_norm * scale
    cnt_scaled = cnt_scaled + [cx, cy]
    cnt_scaled = cnt_scaled.astype(np.int32)

    return cnt_scaled

#GET ORIGINAL CONTOURS
orig_img      = cmyk_to_rgb(str(img_path))
orig_threshed = cv_threshold(orig_img, 254,255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
orig_contours= find_contours(orig_threshed)
orig_mask     = mask_from_contours(orig_img, orig_contours)
orig_output   = draw_contours(orig_img, orig_contours)

#GET DILATED CONTOURS
dilated_mask     = dilate_mask(orig_mask, 80)
dilated_contours= find_contours(dilated_mask)
dilated_output   = draw_contours(orig_img, dilated_contours)

#Just to observe dilation effect
RGBimage = cv2.cvtColor(dilated_output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pilImage = Image.fromarray(RGBimage)
pilImage.save('dilation.png', dpi=(300,300))


# SCALE DILATED CONTOURS
cnt_scaled = scale_contour(dilated_contours[0], 0.95)
im_copy = orig_img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(im_copy, [cnt_scaled], -1, (50, 50, 50), 24)


RGBimage = cv2.cvtColor(im_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pilImage = Image.fromarray(RGBimage)
#Output
pilImage.save('output.png', dpi=(300,300))
```

The images below are an example of the error that sometimes happens: for some shapes or images (input), the dilated contours (the thick line on the second picture) do not match the original shape's contour. Dilated contours are supposed to match the original shape for any given input.

[Input: Original Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCklj.png)

[Bad Output: Original shape + dilated contours scaled in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmbtH.png)

Comment: You're looking for the erosion, the dual of the dilation. After applying a dilation, the erosion would move the edges of the objects back so that the object regains it original size. But holes will remain closed. This composition of dilation + erosion is called closing, because it closes (fills) holes.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you! can you post it as an answer so I can accept your answer?

Comment: Feel free to write an answer yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the ConvexHull concept to fill the gaps.
In `Hull Image` you can see a red line contour it is a `convex hull` of your desire blue line contour.

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("image.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow("Threshold", threshold)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

cnt_hull = cv2.convexHull(contour)

cv2.drawContours(image, [contour], -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.drawContours(image, [cnt_hull], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Hull Image", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think it would be useful for regular shapes, but in the case that the input has inclined lines and irregularities (for example lines going up and down with some inclinations), there would be extra space between the convex hull and the contour of the shape and would not be able to identify only the gaps @VatsalParsaniya